# CloudKit: Incoming CKNotification's pushed repeatedly

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have my CloudKit setup working pretty well using a private DB with a custom zone. Whenever I fetch I send the latest token I have cached previously, and I trigger a fetch every time I get a CKNotification.

However in one occasion while debugging my app I saw it getting CKNotifications repeatedly, and I could verify that indeed I'd get new tokens and I'd send the latest one on each fetch. As for the data changes themselves, it was always the same record. This particular record needed to be discarded on the receiving device, and so it was, but I don't see that as an issue, I'm saving the change token every time and I acknowledge the notification to be processed with .newData. I'd expect that change to never be notified again!

I tried to recreate the scenario with another record that also needs to be discarded but so far everything seems to work as expected. My concern is that any of my users will ever get to that repeating notifications scenario I once saw going on.

Any ideas of what may have caused it?

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried about this. CloudKit does some weird stuff from time-to-time, and this sounds like a temporary glitch to me.

Comment: Hmm... it only stopped when I deleted the record on the original device, it seemed it would go on forever otherwise. Hard to figure out if I don't see it again... :/